# Resultado Tabuada em JavaScript dentro de uma DIV

Tags: javascript, for, div

Fiz um código simples pra uma tabuada usando o "for" só que ao personalizar pro resultado da tabuada sair impresso na DIV eu não consigo. Ele não carrega todos valores. Segue o código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript</title>
  <script>
    function calcular(){
      let valor = document.querySelector('input#valor') // Pega valor digitado no input
      let res = document.querySelector('div#resultado') // Pega div (onde deve inserir resultado)
      let vfinal = valor.value // Pega o valor pra poder fazer a operação matemática
          
      for(let y = 1; y <= 10; y++) {
        
      let multiplicacao = (vfinal * y)
      //document.write( y + ' x ' +valor.value+ ' = ' + (y * valor.value) + '<br>')
      res.innerHTML = `${vfinal} x ${y} = ${multiplicacao} ` // 

      }
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    div {
      border: 1px solid red;
      width: 250px;
      height: 350px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<h1>Tabuada usando For</h1>
<p><input type="number" id="valor">
<input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="calcular()"></p>
<p>
  <div id="resultado">
    Resultado aqui
  </div>
</p>
<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Gostaria que o resultado saísse assim, conforme imagem:

[image: Como gostaria que saísse]

Comment: O `res.innerHTML` atribui um novo conteúdo ao elemento `res`, por isso não estás a conseguir. Você pode usar a [concatenação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings) (usando sinal do +) para obter o resultado, para isso basta adicionar `res.innerHTML = ''` (antes do for) e `res.innerHTML += \`${vfinal} x ${y} = ${multiplicacao}\`` (dentro do for)

Answer (score -1):

Como já dito em um comentário, você está atribuindo um novo conteúdo a sua div a cada iteração do seu loop, você deve concatenar o valor e encerrar a linha utilizando uma tag `<br/>`, simplesmente substituindo:

```
res.innerHTML = `${vfinal} x ${y} = ${multiplicacao} `
```

por:

```
res.innerHTML += `${vfinal} x ${y} = ${multiplicacao} <br/>`;
```

e resetando o conteúdo da sua div colocando a seguinte linha antes do for:

```
  res.innerHTML = "Resultado aqui <br/>";
```

```js
function calcular() {
  let valor = document.querySelector("input#valor"); // Pega valor digitado no input
  let res = document.querySelector("div#resultado"); // Pega div (onde deve inserir resultado)
  let vfinal = valor.value; // Pega o valor pra poder fazer a operação matemática
  res.innerHTML = "Resultado aqui <br/>";
  for (let y = 1; y <= 10; y++) {
    let multiplicacao = vfinal * y;
    //document.write( y + ' x ' +valor.value+ ' = ' + (y * valor.value) + '<br>')

    res.innerHTML += `${vfinal} x ${y} = ${multiplicacao} <br/>`; //
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tabuada usando For</h1>
<p><input type="number" id="valor">
  <input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="calcular()">
</p>
<p>
<div id="resultado">
  Resultado aqui
</div>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Tem outra forma de fazer, bem facil

- HTML

  ```
    <input class="form-control mb-3" type="number" name="num" id="nu1">
         <input type="button" class="btn btn-dark p-2" value="Gerar tabuada" onclick="tabuada()"></input> 
       </div>
       <div class="card-footer text-muted">
         <select class="form-select text-center fs-1 " name="tabuada" id="seltab" size="10"></select>
       </div>
  ```
- Script

  ```
     function tabuada() {
     let num = document.getElementById('nu1')
     let tab = document.getElementById('seltab')
     if(num.value.length == 0) {
         window.alert('Por favor digite o numero')
     }else {
         let n = Number(num.value)
         let c = 1
         tab.innerHTML = ''
         while( c <= 10) {
             let item = document.createElement('option')
             item.text = `${n} X ${c} = ${n*c}`
             tab.value = `tab${c}`
             tab.appendChild(item)
             c++
         }
     }
  ```

  }
- Teste

```js
function tabuada() {
          let num = document.getElementById('nu1')
          let tab = document.getElementById('seltab')
          if(num.value.length == 0) {
              window.alert('Por favor digite o numero')
          }else {
              let n = Number(num.value)
              let c = 1
              tab.innerHTML = ''
              while( c <= 10) {
                  let item = document.createElement('option')
                  item.text = `${n} X ${c} = ${n*c}`
                  tab.value = `tab${c}`
                  tab.appendChild(item)
                  c++
              }
          } 
      }
```

```html
     <input class="form-control mb-3" type="number" name="num" id="nu1">
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-dark p-2" value="Gerar tabuada" onclick="tabuada()"></input> 
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
              <select class="form-select text-center fs-1 " name="tabuada" id="seltab" size="10"></select>
            </div>
```